# setsockopt returning error 10014

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, multicast, setsockopt

I'm trying to write a simple UDP server that advertises its service port on a multicast group but I'm having trouble getting the multicast to work. I tried looking around on the Microsoft documentation and copy/pasted some of their code but it's not working. Here is the problematic code:

```
    this->port = srvc_port; //11129 in my example
    this->mcast_port = mcast_port; //11130 in my example
    this->mcast_ip = mcast_ip; //230.0.0.30 in my example

    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &service_wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "WSAstartup failed" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    service_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (service_sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        closesocket(service_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        cout << "Error at socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    mcast_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if(mcast_sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        closesocket(mcast_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        cout << "Error at socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    multicast.sin_family = AF_INET; // multicast is a sockaddr_in struct
    multicast.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    multicast.sin_port = htons(mcast_port);

    service.sin_family = AF_INET; //same for service
    service.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    service.sin_port = htons(port);

    if(::bind( service_sock, (sockaddr *)&service, sizeof(service) ) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(mcast_sock);
        closesocket(service_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        cout << "Error binding service socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    };

    if(::bind( mcast_sock, (sockaddr *)&multicast, sizeof(multicast) ) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(mcast_sock);
        closesocket(service_sock);
        WSACleanup();
        cout << "Error binding multicast socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    };

    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(mcast_ip.c_str()); //mreq is declared like so "struct ip_mreq mreq;" in the class
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if(setsockopt(mcast_sock,IPPROTO_IP,IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP,(char *) &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
            //I get error 10014 here
        cout << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return -1;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the doc says that 10014 means bad address. We don't see much from your `mreq` variable and its initialization, here you initialize only 2 members out of 3. In case of socket programming its also wise to start the initialization of these structures by memsetting them to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10014 is `WSAEFAULT`, which means *"The buffer pointed to by the optval parameter is not in a valid part of the process address space **or the optlen parameter is too small.**"*

Read the documentation:

[IPPROTO_IP Socket Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

`IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP` expects a pointer to an [`ip_mreq_source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738704%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure:

```
typedef struct ip_mreq_source {
  struct in_addr  imr_multiaddr;
  struct in_addr  imr_sourceaddr;
  struct in_addr  imr_interface;
} IP_MREQ_SOURCE, *PIP_MREQ_SOURCE;
```

You are passing it a pointer to an [`ip_mreq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738695%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure instead:

```
typedef struct ip_mreq {
  struct in_addr  imr_multiaddr;
  struct in_addr  imr_interface;
} IP_MREQ, *PIP_MREQ;
```

`ip_mreq` is smaller than `ip_mreq_source`, thus `sizeof(mreq)` is too small for `IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP`.  You need to change your `mreq` variable to `ip_mreq_source`, and be sure to fill in its `imr_sourceaddr` member.

`ip_mreq` is used for `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` and `IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP`.

`ip_mreq_source` is used for `IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP`, `IP_DROP_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP`, `IP_BLOCK_SOURCE`, and `IP_UNBLOCK_SOURCE`.